# How to query and display longest name of row results with same id, same date, and same first name

Tags: sql

For each same id, same date, and same first name, I would like to display the shortest last name through a group by or any other workaround:

Here's the table:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTUqh.jpg

Here's the results I would like to see:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Fwot.jpg

I was wondering if someone could show me how to do this with a query.

Thanks

Comment: You may want to take a minute to reformat your question...[How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also check out [Why not to use pictures](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question), gives a good overview of the many reasons not to use images.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I skimmed through your links as well. I figured images from these links may be more helpful in explaining things visually.

Comment: I would do this via whatever program you are using (i.e. PHP), but here is how to get a length of a string: SELECT LEN('W3Schools.com');

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this, here are two. As you haven't tagged anything other than sql, I am not sure which program you are using or the syntax you require. I use sql server 2008 r2, so that is the code you see. If you use mysql, oracle, another sql server version or something else, please tag it.

Here is base data:

```
SELECT 1 as ID, '2019-01-01' as [Date], 'Edward Brady' as LastName, 'Tom' as FirstName
into #table
UNION
SELECT 1 as ID, '2019-01-01' as [Date], 'Brady' as LastName, 'Tom' as FirstName
UNION
SELECT 2 as ID, '2019-02-02' as [Date], 'Wardell Curry' as LastName, 'Steph' as FirstName
UNION
SELECT 2 as ID, '2019-02-02' as [Date], 'Curry' as LastName, 'Steph' as FirstName
UNION
SELECT 2 as ID, '2019-02-02' as [Date], 'Curry II' as LastName, 'Steph' as FirstName
UNION
SELECT 3 as ID, '2019-03-03' as [Date], 'Ronaldo' as LastName, 'Christiano' as FirstName
UNION
SELECT 3 as ID, '2019-03-03' as [Date], 'Ronaldo' as LastName, 'Christiano' as FirstName
```

You can use a Common Table Expression(CTE) and join it back on the actual length of the string.

```
WITH CTE AS
    (SELECT Distinct ID
                    ,Date
                    ,Firstname
                    ,Min(len(LastName)) as Shortest
     FROM #table
     GROUP BY ID
             ,Date
             ,FirstName)
SELECT   t.ID
        ,t.Date
        ,t.lastname
        ,t.firstname
FROM #table t
JOIN CTE c ON c.ID = t.ID
           AND LEN(Lastname) = Shortest
```

This is a Similar Idea, but done without using a Join and using ROW_NUMBER.

```
WITH CTE AS
    (SELECT Distinct ID
                    ,Date
                    ,Firstname
                    ,LastName
                    ,ROW_NUMBER() over (Partition By ID ORDER BY LEN(LastName) ASC) as Rnk
     FROM #table)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE
WHERE Rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all last names that are shortest for each `id`:

```
select t.*
from t
where len(t.lastname) = (select min(len(t2.lastname))
                         from t t2
                         where t2.id = t.id
                        );
```

Actually, in this case, to choose one of them, `row_number()` is a good solution:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by len(lastname) asc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```